# Arch Linux - wifi-menu suddenly stopped working

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I was following a tutorial on how to install arch, and my wifi-menu command suddenly stopped working after I edited pacman.conf and added a new user. I don't know if this is the cause, and I doubt it, but it was at that point that I started getting THIS:

[image: The output]

Everytime I run wifi-menu.

Output of systemctl status netctl@virgin.service:
[image: Output]

Comment: Did you follow the error directive and read what was printed to the journal?

Comment: @jasonwryan yes but it wasn't very informative...

Comment: Please [don't paste images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). You can get more information with `journalctl _PID=XXX`

Comment: @jasonwryan I had to.... And what pid do i enter?

Comment: The PID that is printed in the journal status...

Comment: @jasonwryan seems i dont have journalctl... Strange

Answer (score 1):

Boot from USB installation stick, mount your directories, chroot into your system. Then execute:

`pacman -S iw wpa_supplicant dialog`

Then reboot into your system and try

`wifi-menu -o`

**UPDATE 1**

Actually, you might want to try another solution - for example, try `networkmanager`. [You can read about it](http://You%20can%20read%20about%20it) and execute:

```
pacman -S networkmanager

systemctl stop netctl@virgin

systemctl disable netctl@virgin

systemctl start NetworkManager

systemctl enable NetworkManager
```

Comment: I already had all the dependencies installed, so that didn't help...

Comment: Then do what the system wants: provide the output of `systemctl status netctl@virgin`. It could be a hardware issue.

Comment: okay... But I cant copy and paste so I'll add a photo. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, update your initial question.

Comment: oh, and also during boot when it says dhcpcd start job running it ends in a failure... Hope that helps.

Comment: Going with `networkmanager` looks like the easiest solution alright.  Just remember to not enable/start a `dhcpcd` service together with `netwrokmanager` since the later starts a DHCP client on its own.

Comment: `systemctl disable dhcpcd%press TAB here to complete the command%`. Then `enable` NetworkManager just to be sure. Then reboot.

Comment: I have executed all of those, rebooted, now what?

Comment: Now you should have a working connection. If not - provide all the details about the errors you get in your question. Read archwiki's "Wireless" page, maybe your network card needs additional software.

Comment: Its also interesting that it works fine on the live usb

Comment: Nnnnññnnnñnnññnnnnñnnnnnnnnnnnñnñnnnnnnnnnnnmñnnnnn